# Insert on Button Click

Tags: android, sqlite

Why does my application crash when I click my `button` and how do I fix it?

I need to insert a `row` into my `SQLite` `database` when a button is clicked. It contains two values, which should be easy enough. One is a `date`, formatted using the `simpledateformatter`. The other is simply a location from an `ArrayList`. I have no red lines in my code, but my app crashes when I press the button to `insert` the row. Below is code from the 3 `Java` files interacting with each other. I have a hunch the problem lies in my Model.java, however it could be more than that. If more code is needed just ask.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final String TAG = "*** DEBUG ***";

public static final String SMOKIN_DATA_FILE = "smokin.dat";
public static final int EDIT_ACTIVITY = 1;

public static Model model = null;
public static MySmokinDatabase mySmokinDatabase;
public static Cursor cursor;
public static SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    restoreModel();

    if (mySmokinDatabase == null)
        mySmokinDatabase = new MySmokinDatabase(this);

    refreshView();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (model == null)
        restoreModel();

    refreshView();
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    saveModel();
}

private void refreshView() {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.location_spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, model.getLocationsArray());

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd");

    TextView dateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    TextView countText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
    TextView daysText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.days);
    TextView totalText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
    TextView aveText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ave);

    GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
    dateText.setText(sdf.format(now.getTime()));
    //get today's count from data in the SQLite table - count entries with today's date
    countText.setText("" + "");
    //mySmokinDatabase.getTodaysCount());

    // Table data
    daysText.setText("" + String.format("%10d", model.getDays()));
    totalText.setText("" + "get total count from data in SQLite table - count total rows");

    if (model.getDays() > 0)
        aveText.setText("calc average from SQLite and model info");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == EDIT_ACTIVITY) { 
        saveModel();
    }
}

public void smokedHandler(View view) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.location_spinner);

    String s = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String d = model.getDates();

    mySmokinDatabase.insertSmokinValues(new Model(s,d));

    cursor = mySmokinDatabase.getAllSmokinCursor();
    adapter.changeCursor(cursor);   

    refreshView();
}

public void restoreModel() {
    // Restore from disk, or start with an empty model
    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                openFileInput(SMOKIN_DATA_FILE));

        model = (Model) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.v("*** DEBUG ***", "Error writing to file: " + e);
        model = new Model();
    }
}

public void saveModel() {
    Log.v("*** AJ ***", "In onPause");

    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                openFileOutput(SMOKIN_DATA_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));

        oos.writeObject(model);
        oos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.v("*** MatchIt ***", "Error writing to file: " + e);
    }
}
```

**DB File**

```
public long insertSmokinValues(Model model) {
    ContentValues newSmokinValues = new ContentValues();
    newSmokinValues.put(KEY_DATE, model.getDates());
    newSmokinValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, model.getLocations());        
    SQLiteDatabase db = smokinDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    return db.insert(SmokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE, null, newSmokinValues);
}

public Cursor getAllSmokinCursor() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = smokinDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    return db.query(SmokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE, new String[] 
            {KEY_ID, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_DATE}, null, null, null, null, null);        
}
```

**Model File**

```
private ArrayList<String> locations = new ArrayList<String>();
public String [] defaultLocations = {"Home", "Work", "Commuting", "School", "Bar", 
"Restaurant", "Social Gathering", "Other"};

public Model(GregorianCalendar date){
    startDate = date;

    for (String s : this.defaultLocations)
        locations.add(s);
}

public Model(String s, String d) {
    place = s;
    dates = d;      
}

public String getDates() {
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    dates = sdf.format(gc.getTime());       

    return dates;
}   

public String getLocations() {
    for (String s : this.locations)
        place = s;
    return place;
}
```

**As requested log cat:**

```
 03-18 15:52:42.397: W/dalvikvm(676): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught  
 exception
 (group=0x40a13300)
 03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not    
execute method of the activity
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at    
android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at   
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at   
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at   
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at   
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at   
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at    
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at    
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native   
Method)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676): Caused by: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at   
android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  ... 11 more
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at     
com.example.smokin4ThomasSullivan.MainActivity.smokedHandler(MainActivity.java:119)
03-18 15:52:42.457: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  ... 14 more
```

> line 119: adapter.changeCursor(cursor); The method involved is posted in my DB file

As always any help is appreciated!

Comment: Post the stack trace from your logcat.

Comment: without logcat we do nothing.

Comment: logcat posted, sorry about that. Also added another method into the DB file

Comment: you have NPE in smokedHandler() method. something is null there.

Comment: What's on line 119? You're trying to use a null object.

Comment: it seems your cursor is null

Comment: Well until I click this button there are no values in the database. So the cursor which is returning "all values" is returning nothing, because there is nothing in the database.

Comment: As an aside, you should understand that there is no connection between "red lines", i.e. compiler errors and crashes i.e. runtime errors since you cannot get the latter before you eliminate the former.  `x=1;y=0;z=x/y` will compile (no red lines) just fine but will crash when you run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log says everything: you're trying to use `adapter` which is `null` in this line:

```
adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
```

Edit:

As I thought, you declare your `adapter` field here:

```
public static SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
```

But you don't initialize it, and as you should know in Java if you declare a field without initialization, it's set to `null`. That's why you get your error.

I haven't personally used `SimpleCursorAdapter` class, but you might want to take a look at constructor for it which is described in android documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

So basically inside `onCreate()` method, you should do something like this:

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter( this, 
                                   R.layout.some_layout,
                                   cursor,
                                   columns,
                                   to,
                                   0 );
```

Used constructor's parameters are described in documentation to which I posted link earlier.

You might also want to check this code which uses `SimpleCursorAdapter`:
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

Comment: Well until I click this button there are no values in the database. The database consists of dates and locations. This button adds those entries. So the cursor which is returning "all values" is returning nothing, because there is nothing in the database. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Where does the log say the `adapter` is null? It could be anything in that method without the line numbers.

Comment: @Tushar He just posted what is in line 119. Check out his edit.

Comment: @Mosquito aah, I see. Sorry about that, then :)

Comment: @IrishWhiskey First of all error which you get doesn't have anything to do with `cursor`. The second thing is that you should make sure that database is filled when user is clicking a button.

Comment: @Mosquito That seems to make a lot more sense. Any thoughts on a solution? You seem to have the best answer thus far

Comment: Initialize `adapter`? :-) Show us where and how you do that, because if it's `null` then it's either not initialized because you forgot about it, or it's not initialized properly.

Comment: lol, you may be right. I probably need to step away from the computer for a minute because that's a pretty basic error, even for me. I posted a more comprehensive MainActivity up top, take a look. I'm gonna take 5 and come back

Comment: @IrishWhiskey I edited my answer, take a look. :-) I'll probably be more helpful tomorrow if you still need help, cause for now I don't really have time to explain it better. Anyway I hope it's enough.

Comment: cool, that worked. Answer accepted as it was the most direct and efficient. I will be posting my finished code once its done for anyone else who may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
Like others guys say. It is correct that the `adapter` is responsible for the `NPE`

However it is also important to adopt the right way by dealing with Sqlite `cursor`.

It is important to do following

**replace**

```
public Cursor getAllSmokinCursor() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = smokinDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    return db.query(SmokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE, new String[] 
            {KEY_ID, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_DATE}, null, null, null, null, null);        
}
```

**with**

```
public List<Model> getAllSmokinCursor() {
   List<Model> models= new ArrayList<Model>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = smokinDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor= db.query(SmokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE, new String[] 
            {KEY_ID, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_DATE}, null, null, null, null, null);        

 cursor.moveToFirst();
      while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
         Model device = fromCursorToObject(cursor);

         models.add(device);
         cursor.moveToNext();
      }
      // Make sure to close the cursor
      cursor.close();
      return models;
```

}

I use here a list because you don't have any restriction in your requestpublic static Device

```
fromCursorToObject(Cursor cursor) {
      Model model = new Model();
      int i = 0;
      model.setId(cursor.getLong(i++));
      model.setLocation(cursor.getString(i++));
      model.setDate(cursor.getString(i++));
      return model;
   }
```

i assume that you must add getter/setter to your Model class and also ID field (private Long id)

Comment: checking the solution now, if you don't mind could you explain the `while-loop` to me? Not sure I fully understand what its doing there.

Comment: @IrishWhiskey if you don't have any restriction in your query it can return a list that is why  i use while-loop

Comment: If he gets `NullPointerException` in place the log mentions, then it's not a `cursor`'s, but `adapter`'s fault.

Comment: It appears as though this could work, but I am far to new to understand fully what the code is doing here. I get lost @ Model device = Method_to_transform_cursor_to_model(cursor); which looks like psuedo code. I'll look into this, though it may take me a little while

Comment: @IrishWhiskey i just update my post to add a method to transform cursor into model object

Comment: @FestusTamakloe this seems like a rather long solution. That's not to say its wrong, it just seems like an awful lot of code for a rather simple solution. When I'm done studying cursor/adapter and my code is running properly I will explore your solution in more detail. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, and your time

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should close the database in these functions :

```
public long insertSmokinValues(Model model) {
    ContentValues newSmokinValues = new ContentValues();
    newSmokinValues.put(KEY_DATE, model.getDates());
    newSmokinValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, model.getLocations());        
    SQLiteDatabase db = smokinDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    return db.insert(SmokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE, null, newSmokinValues);
}

public Cursor getAllSmokinCursor() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = smokinDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    return db.query(SmokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE, new String[] 
            {KEY_ID, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_DATE}, null, null, null, null, null);        
}
```

Second if you don't want to change the cursor in the adapter when there is no results in `gestSmokinCursor` simply check with `moveToFirst` if the cursor contains a result, if not throw a custom exception say `EmptyCursorException` which you can handle when you get the cursor.

Also you need to think about how you are closing your cursors, as I'm not sure if your adapter is closing the cursors when you change them and when the activity is destroyed, but this is also your responsibility.

---

If your `NullPointerException` is on this line:

```
adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
```

Then your adapter is simply `null` and needs to be initiated and this has nothing to do with the database, however there are still a lot of problems with your code that you should address, otherwise you will encounter errors and leaks when people start using the app.

Comment: you are probably 100% correct. As this is homework though I think the professor is trying to deliberately teach us something. He often goes back over the assignment when after it's due and posts proper conventions and more realistic solutions. Just because it runs, doesn't mean it was programmed properly. I understand that.

Comment: @IrishWhiskey I understand that you are just trying to get it to run and the things I pointed out will help you tackle the exceptions you will receive after you get the `NullPointerException` sorted out. The code your wrote will throw exceptions even if the adapter is not `null`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I need to study more about `cursor` and `adapter`. You have definitely pointed me in the right direction though and by the time I'm done studying I'm sure your post will make perfect sense